# Automaticly fill my (time value) array with a for loop, doesn't add values to previous array - ASP CLASSIC

Tags: arrays, for-loop, asp-classic

I am programming a function in which I can populate my array with some values. I want to populate them because the array is way to big to fill it myself.

The array is a set of time values from which a person can choose in a dropdown (selection). The default should be 7:30 (european time) and the dates to choose from should have steps of 15 minutes. The lowest time to choose from is 5.00 and the highest is 23:00, which is a total of 18 hours. so with steps of 15 minutes that means: 18 hours x 60 minutes =  1080 minutes / 15 minutes = 72 steps of 15 minutes. So that is a total of 71 array values (counting the 0 as well).

Now the function i figured out is as follows:

```
Dim myArray

ReDim myArray(5)

Dim counter

For counter = 0 To UBound(myArray)
     if counter = 0 then 
        myArray(counter) = Hour("05:00")
    else
        myArray(counter) = DateAdd("n",15,myArray(counter))
    end if 
Next

For Each item In myArray 
    Response.Write(item & "<br />")
Next
```

This bit was just for the testing:

```
  For Each item In myArray 
        Response.Write(item & "<br />")
    Next
```

Though the looping doesn't add the 15 minutes, instead it starts with the 5.00 but then keeps printing the 00:15 after the first counter, so it doesnt add the 15 minutes to its last count value.

Any clue how to fix it?

The output is as follows while testing the array with a count of 5:

```
5
00:15:00
00:15:00
00:15:00
00:15:00
00:15:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out myself. 
I did it now by adding the value to a variable which changes in every loop to a new (the added 15 minute) value. This way it adds the 15 minutes to the latest value.

**The code:**

```
Dim myArray

ReDim myArray(5)

Dim counter
Dim BeginTijdArray 

BeginTijdArray = Hour("05:00") & ":" & Minute("05:00")

For counter = 0 To UBound(myArray)
     if counter = 0 then 
        myArray(counter) = BeginTijdArray
    else 
        myArray(counter) = DateAdd("n",15,BeginTijdArray)
        myArray(counter) = Hour(myArray(counter)) & ":" & Minute(myArray(counter))
        BeginTijdArray = myArray(counter)
    end if 
Next

For Each item In myArray 
    Response.Write(item & "<br />")
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe there is a simple bug in your loop.

This line

```
myArray(counter) = DateAdd("n",15,myArray(counter))
```

should be

```
myArray(counter) = DateAdd("n",15,myArray(counter - 1))
```

I think that is all.

Comment: Didn't quite work. It adds the 15 minutes but not from the starting time (05:00) and also it adds the entire date in front of it for some reasson.. The output now is:  `5
4-1-1900 00:15:00
4-1-1900 00:30:00
4-1-1900 00:45:00
4-1-1900 01:00:00
4-1-1900 01:15:00`  So first 5 then 4-1-1900 00:15and from here on it adds..

Comment: Adding `myArray(counter) = Hour(myArray(counter)) & ":" & Minute(myArray(counter))` partial helps, it removes the entiredate (year, month) but still doesnt solves the not counting from 5 problem.